# How to convert this PHP regex into JS

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have the following RegEx that works in PHP, but I can't figure out how to convert it so that it works in JS.

```
$string='test/again/'
preg_replace('/[^\/]+\/$/', '', $string)
```

this takes this:
test/again/

and makes it into:
test/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what hindered you from typing in "regex replace javascript" into Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) should do the trick

```
var string = 'test/again/'
string = string.replace(/[^\/]+\/$/,'');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I thought I needed to escape the slashes, because when I was testing it, it wasn't working. All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

`/[^\/]+\/$/` should do the trick.

**Edit**: I see that you edited your post, and your RegExp now just looks the same. What's your question again?

Comment: I'm upvoting this just for the comedy value.

Comment: The original post was edited, and was asking how to _convert the regular expression_ from PHP to JS, not how to use it to replace substrings.

Comment: No no, the OP asked how to make the *regex* work in JS. This answers the question.

Comment: English may not be my mother language, but I'm pretty sure that "it" in "convert it" refers to the RegExp, not to `preg_replace`. You may say that the question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()`:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/XEy8p/)

```
var string = 'test/again/';
var result = string.replace(/[^\/]+\/$/, '');
```